# Find elements in a character array that contains a string

Tags: string, r

I want to extract the elements of a character array that contains some particular string. For example:

```
x <- c('aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'bb', 'bc')
```

I want some function such that, given `x` and `'a'`(in general this can be a string), it returns `'aa', 'ab', 'ac'`. I have experimented with a combination of `%in%`, `match`, `which`, etc, but have not been able to make them work. Any idea?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Just use `grep`:

```
grep('a', x, value=TRUE)
[1] "aa" "ab" "ac"
```

Answer (score 0):

In a table or a list, we can use dplyr::pull from dplyr/tidyverse package to convert values in a column to a vector first and then find the particular value in the column. For instance, in the LEGO example, we can do the following to find any theme starting by "s" or "S":

```
 inventory_parts_themes <- inventories %>%
   inner_join(inventory_parts, by = c("id" = "inventory_id")) %>%
     arrange(desc(quantity)) %>%
       select(-id, -version) %>%
         inner_join(sets, by = "set_num") %>%
            inner_join(themes, by = c("theme_id" = "id"), suffix = c("_set", "_theme"))

  all_theme_names <- dplyr::pull(inventory_parts_themes, name_theme) 
  all_theme_names[grep("^[sS].*", all_theme_names)]
```